# AutoCompleteSupportFragment keeps disabling it's self after place selection

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

I'm using an AutoCompleteFragment in my application and after I press the search button, type in a place and the select it nothing happens. The PlaceSelection listener that I have attached to AutocompleteFragment is never called; even without error. It also seems as though the fragment has disabled it's self because when I press the search bar again I get this error in the log "Places: Autocomplete activity cannot be launched until fragment is enabled." which is odd because I never disable it in my code.

Im currently using

```
com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0
```

Comment: Are you using the deprecated [AutocompleteFragment](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/places/widget/AutocompleteFragment) or [AutocompleteSupportFragment](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/places/widget/AutocompleteSupportFragment)? Have you fully migrated to the new Places SDK? If you try [this exact code](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#option_1_embed_an_autocompletesupportfragment) from Google's guide, does it work for you?

Comment: Also please post your manifest, build.gradle and your code implementation so that we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys i actually found the solution to my error. I wasnt calling the super method in my overriden onActivityResult method. I tried posting my code, manafest, etc but stack overflow keep throwing me an error when i tried to submit.

Comment: Thanks for your update, glad to hear you found the problem and fixed it. :)